# How to convert bytestring to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion

The function:

```
def write_file():
    f = open('image.txt', 'wb')
    byte_arr = getbytes(read_bits())
    byte_list = list(byte_arr)
    print(byte_list)
    some_bytes = bytearray(byte_list)
    print(bytes(some_bytes))
    st = bytes(some_bytes).decode('latin1')
    immutable_bytes = bytes(some_bytes)
    with open('test','wb') as f:
         f.write(immutable_bytes )
```

The output is like:

```
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0]
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00'
```

I want to write string value converted from this list of byte values.

Comment: So you want to convert it to regular text?

Comment: Yes exactly Ruslan Tolstikau

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
st = bytes(some_bytes).decode('utf-8')
with open('test','wb') as f:
     f.write(st)
```

instead of this:

```
st = bytes(some_bytes).decode('latin1')
immutable_bytes = bytes(some_bytes)
with open('test','wb') as f:
     f.write(immutable_bytes )
```